# How to filter out my logcat in android studio?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, filter, logcat

In Android Studio I connected my device and I can see the outputs of every single running application but i want to see the logs form only one application, I went to the filter and put in "anrdoid.kik" which is was the process is called but no logs showed up. I then went to the search bar and wrote the same thing, some logs showed up but it wasn't live no other logs were being shown live. I checked the name of the process by enabling "show processes " in my developer menu on my android but so far nothing seems to work any solutions? Using the search bar to filter by kik works but i also wish to check the network logs too and I dont think using only the keyword kik doesn't exactly work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open Android Device Monitor, on the side with `Saved Filters`you click on `+` and add your application `by Application Name`. Also note that applications in `release version` (applications downloaded from play store) will not show up, because they don't have debugging messages allowed - not even in alpha release.

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks so is there any possible way to be able to look at live logs for apps like kik? Or do i have to download the apk and reverse engineer them?

Comment: You can't get logs of apps released in Play Store like this - google actually prohibits that. So yes, you'd have to rev. eng. it

Comment: @Hooga also, feel free to accept the answer to get it out of unanswered queue.